# fullPage.js anchor scroll chrome bug

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, fullpage.js

I'm working on a site: http://hopscotch.laurent.devops.montenasoft.com 
when you click on the hamburger menu (top right) -> then hopscotch congress or our values (only these 2 are configured) it should scroll to the second section and it works on firefox but not on chrome.

There is a lot of js written in a rush. Most of it in http://hopscotch.laurent.devops.montenasoft.com/sites/all/themes/hopscotch/js/main.js

I can copy some part that I think is relevant but not sure what causes the bug.
Only if someone can point to a peace of code that he/she thinks it can cause the bug it would help a lot...

Part of the js is not written by me but I will try to answer questions.

ps

It works on chrome when you open a new tab with the first 2 links.

**update**

The task is to create a link to a page that scrolls down to a section and changes the slide to a specific slide. The slide part is working only not the scroll down part.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using anchors links in your menu as specified in [fullPage.js docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) or [examples](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/examples). You are just calling another URL:

See the difference:

**New URL**

> www.site.com/en?img=0#second

**Anchor link**

> www.site.com/#second

Fullpage.js only works with **anchor links**.

The only reason it might work in Firefox is due to the way they treat URLs with new parameters. But this might change in the future at any point. Not something you can rely on.

Example available in fullPage.js docs:

```
<ul id="myMenu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="active"><a href="#firstPage">First section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Second section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="thirdPage"><a href="#thirdPage">Third section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="fourthPage"><a href="#fourthPage">Fourth section</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The task i was given was to make links to pages on the site that on load scroll to the specified section. Is this somehow possible with the fullpage js?

Comment: Why would you want to load a new page in a one page site? Sounds bad to me.

Comment: there are 2 more http://hopscotch.laurent.devops.montenasoft.com/en/pco and http://hopscotch.laurent.devops.montenasoft.com/en/he that is the only reason im going for the url. I need to be able to go there and back to a specific section and slide

Comment: The link from [here](http://hopscotch.laurent.devops.montenasoft.com/en/pco) to [here](http://hopscotch.laurent.devops.montenasoft.com/en#second) by clicking in the menu works as expected.